# PHP DomDoc & XPath get number of unknown child elements

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I retrieve the contents of a website with DomDoc and query for certain elements with XPath. For example I query for `<p>` Elements - by doing something like this inside a Loop `$paragraphs = $dom->query('//p')->item(i);` and then continue to manipulate the `<p>` inside the loop. Now, is there a way to find out what kind of other HTML elements are maybe inside the `<p>` and how many other elements are inside the paragraph element?

I have seen this example : [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.count.php)

But this only seems to work if you know something about the child elements? how can I get the count and element name if the "contents" of the `<p></p>`is unknown to me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on any DOM element you have you can use `getElementsByTagName('*')` to find all descendant elements or you can use XPath relative to the element to find all child element with the path `*` or count them with the XPath expression `count(*)` or you can do the same for all descendant elements using `.//*` respectively `count(.//*)`.

So given `$element = $dom->query('//p')->item(i);` you can use `$element->getElementsByTagName('*')->length` as the DOM way to find all descendants, or `$dom->query('.//*', $element)` as the XPath way. For the child elements use `$dom->query('*', $element)`.

Comment: this is working beautifully. thank you! do you also know of a way to retrieve the name of the descendants? Because I have to identify what kind of HTML Elements are present inside the `<p>` (by name I don't mean a html attribute "name", I'm talking about the HTML Element Name, the actual Tag)

Comment: The properties of the nodes are documented, see http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.localname, so you can use `$element->localName`.